# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't indent with tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to achieve Visual Studio 2019 to indent using tabs and not spaces?
I've set `Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Keep tabs` but every time I break something to a new line of code, the automatic indentation still inserts 4 spaces instead of using tabs.
This works for Visual Studio 2017, but not 2019.
Is there another way to achieve it here?!

Comment: Are you running the latest version?

Comment: You're right. Updated to latest version and now it also works in 2019. Thank you for that.

Comment: Nice it's working now!