# Visual Studio 2019 is inserting tabs on enter when it should be using spaces

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having a problem where I press enter at the end of the line and the cursor appears on the next line. When you type your first character the editor should be inserting spaces for the indent but it is inserting tabs.
Under 'Options | Text Editor | All Languages | Tabs' I have 'Insert spaces' and Tab size and Indent size are 2.
Under 'Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Tabs' I have Smart Indenting and 'Insert spaces' with Tab size and Indent size are 2.

Am I missing another option?

Comment: I have the same problem on two different machines running VS2019 in c++

Comment: I discovered that if the document is reformatted to use spaces for indenting it keeps using spaces for indenting afterwards. Reverse for indenting with tabs.  Looks like the option doesn't work and is overridden by how the file is currently formatted. In both cases tabs are kept for positioning comments. Very annoying.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816503/visual-studio-2019-ignoring-tab-preference

Answer (score 3):

So what I discovered is kind of embarrassing. Someone in our group decided to play a joke and created a .editconfig file. I didn't realize this and wasn't even looking for it.
So maybe look to see if that might be it.
But the link 'doug' provided is also very important. That one caught me another time.

Thanks everyone.