# Just installed v16.8.3 of visual studio and I seem to be getting tabs for F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

instead of spaces.

I use F# quite a lot, not had this problem before. My F# settings seem to imply tabs are converted to 4 spaces..."insert spaces = 4"

v16.8.3

very odd

(actually this is a new install on a fresh machine not an upgrade, that may be relevant....I may have done something on my normal machine many moons ago, that Ive now forgotten)

Comment: I have the same problem with C++ in v16.7.x and newer. But C++ isn't picky about tabs like F# is.

Comment: I think this is the Adaptive Formatting behavior in Visual Studio: To turn off this behavior, please go to Tools > Options, and then Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck "Use adaptive formatting".

Comment: This happened to me also, and I thought I was seeing things! Then the problem magically went away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816503/visual-studio-2019-ignoring-tab-preference

Comment: RIght on; but it looks like the other question has never been accepted. 

Comment: ok, so for me it comes and goes, not sure quite when it turns them into tabs, I've now turned off adaptive formatting behaviour....give me 24 hours, if that works I'll let you know

Comment: @wp78de....see below...this fixed it, see below if you want the answer points

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd Oh, I missed the discussion. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the Adaptive Formatting behavior in Visual Studio: To turn off this behavior, please go to Tools > Options, and then Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck "Use adaptive formatting"

If you leave adaptive formatting on the editor might still guess correctly (over time) but the outcome is less predictable, esp. for F#.

Answer (score 0):

from the comments above (@wp78de...if you post this as the answer I'll mark it as such).

"I think this is the Adaptive Formatting behavior in Visual Studio: To turn off this behavior, please go to Tools > Options, and then Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck "Use adaptive formatting"."

this worked for me.