# Visual Studio 2019 F# is Inserting Tabs instead of Spaces

Tags: visual-studio, f#

All of a sudden Visual studio is inserting Tabs instead of spaces and I can't figure out how to switch it back.

It is set to spaces in

```
Tools>Options>Text Editor>All Languages>Tabs
Tools>Options>Text Editor>F#>Tabs
```

There are no extra plugins or anything.

I have tried switching to Tabs, saving and then back.

I'm baffled!

Comment: Do you have an `.editorconfig` file in scope for your project?

Comment: In scenarios like this I just stop and start VS2019 and often clears things up. I know it is a very basic point and I am not being condescending - I have wasted much time not doing what I suggested here myself, in the past.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255258/just-installed-v16-8-3-of-visual-studio-and-i-seem-to-be-getting-tabs-for-f

Comment: @DrewNoakes, you are a lifesaver! :) This was driving me crazy, because I downloaded a project and all of a sudden, I had only spaces. I check all settings a hundred times, restarted VS2019 and so on, and nothing helped. I had another project where this didn't happen, so I was totally astounded why it worked here and not there. Never heard about that `.editorconfig` before, is this some new feature?